# Reactive form dynamic field validation not working for <Select>

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form that contains form array when the user clicks on a button, a  new form group is pushed to the form array. When the user submits the form I want to validate whether those dynamic fields are empty
`room.errors?.required` is not executed. What I am doing wrong here? Other fields are working as I expected. This issue occurs only in the dynamic field.

```js
    this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      description: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(300)]],
      roomTypes: this.formBuilder.array([this.createRoomTypeFeild(),this.createRoomTypeFeild()
      ]),
    });
```

this method is used for creating dynamic form field when the user click on the button

```js
    createRoomTypeFeild(): FormGroup {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
            id: [""],
            room: ["",Validators.required],
            price: ["",Validators.required]
        });
    }
```

this is simple getter I used to get the field to  the template

```js
    get extraRoomTypes() {
        return this.hospitalForm.get("roomTypes") as FormArray;
    }
```

when the user clicks on a button this method executes

```js
    addMoreFeilds(feildName: string) {
        let formArray: FormArray = this.hospitalForm.get(feildName) as FormArray;
        if (feildName === "roomTypes") formArray.push(this.createRoomTypeFeild());
    }
```

Template

```html
    <tr formArrayName="roomTypes" *ngFor="let roomType of extraRoomTypes.controls;let i = index">
        <td>
            <div [formGroupName]="i" class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group row">

                        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label form-field">Room</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9 table-input">

                            <select formControlName="room" type="text" class="form-control">
                                <option [ngValue]="room.id" *ngFor="let room of filterdRoomTypes">{{room.roomType}}</option>
                            </select>
                            <div *ngIf="isSubmitted && hospitalForm.errors" class="error-msg">
                                <div *ngIf="room.errors?.required">
                                    Room is required
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label pl-0 form-field">Price

                        </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input formControlName="pricePerNight" currencyMask [options]="{ prefix: '$ ', thousands: ',', decimal: '.',align:'left' }" type="text" class="form-control price">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: pls try qualify it: extraRoomTypes[i].room

Comment: `extraRoomTypes.at(i).get('room')?.errors?.required`, room is nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you code you have used **room.errors?.required** but room is just a form control name. You need to refer it properly :

```
extraRoomTypes.controls[i].get('room')?.hasError('required')
```

or

```
extraRoomTypes.controls[i].get('room')?.errors?.required
```

Answer (score 1):

As of your given info:

```
<tr formArrayName="roomTypes" *ngFor="let roomType of extraRoomTypes.controls;let i = index">
```

should be like :

```
 <tr formArrayName="roomTypes" *ngFor="let roomType of hospitalForm.controls.roomTypes.controls;let i = index">
```

And for message try like :

```
 <div *ngIf="isSubmitted && roomTypes.controls.room.errors?.required" class="error-msg">
       is required
 </div>
```